# How fetch data from sqlite database in Android, Nuxt, Capacitor

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor, nuxt3

I have a app using Nuxt, Ionic, and Capacitor. In the app I am using sqlite to store some data locally. In the app I am using Nuxt server api to fetch the stored data in the sqlite database locally, and in the browser everything was working fine. But, upon deploying to android emulator it is not able to fetch the data from the sqlite database.

So, if anyone can suggests how sqlite data handling is normally done in capacitor/android. If anyone can suggest me an approach to handle this.

I am using drizzle as a db connector.

I have tried how it is done in this blog: https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/drizzle-orm-sqlite-and-nuxt-js-getting-started-374m

I am using nuxt server api to fetch data into ionic component:

API:

```
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";
import { standards } from "../../db/schema";
import { db } from "../sqlite-service";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const query = getQuery(event)
    const limit = parseInt(query.param1 as string)
    const offset = parseInt(query.param2 as string)

    const standardsResp = db.select().from(standards).limit(limit).offset(offset).all();
    const totalCount = db.select({ count: sql<number>`count(*)` }).from(standards).all();

    return {
         "standards" : standardsResp,
         "totalCount" : totalCount
        }
  } catch (e: any) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: e.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Fetching data into ionic component:

```
const fetchStandards = async (offset = 0) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/standards?param1=${PAGE_SIZE}&param2=${offset}`);
    const responseData = await response.json();

    if (responseData && responseData.standards) {
      standards.value = [...standards.value, ...responseData.standards];

      if (standards.value.length >= responseData.totalCount[0].count) {
        allDataLoaded.value = true;
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching standards:", error);
  }
};
```